# Outward normal component of vector

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I have encountered this question while studying the derivation of the heat equation in two or three dimensions. In Haberman's PDE text, he provides the following figure:
[image]

Here, $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ is the heat flux vector, and the magnitude of $\phi$ is the amount of heat energy flowing per unit time per unit surface area. The vector $\boldsymbol{\hat{n}}$ is the unit outward normal vector.

Looking at point $B$, the author says "the outward normal component of the heat flux vector is $\lvert \boldsymbol{\phi} \rvert \cos \theta = \boldsymbol{\phi} \cdot\boldsymbol{n}/\lvert \boldsymbol{n} \rvert = \boldsymbol{\phi} \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{n}} $."

I agree that the outward normal component of the heat flux vector is $\lvert \boldsymbol{\phi} \rvert \cos \theta $. I also agree that $\boldsymbol{\phi} \cdot\boldsymbol{n}/\lvert \boldsymbol{n} \rvert = \boldsymbol{\phi} \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{n}} $.

However, I am struggling to see why $\lvert \boldsymbol{\phi} \rvert \cos \theta = \boldsymbol{\phi} \cdot\boldsymbol{n}/\lvert \boldsymbol{n} \rvert$. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The magnitude of the dot product $a\cdot b$ is the product of $|a|$ with $|b|\cos\theta$, where the angle is the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$.

Comment: (In a general inner product space, that formula is the *definition* of $\theta$.)

Comment: @symplectomorphic I see: $ \boldsymbol{\phi} \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{n}} = \lvert \boldsymbol{\phi} \rvert \lvert \boldsymbol{\hat{n}} \rvert \cos \theta = \lvert \boldsymbol{\phi} \rvert \cos \theta$? (I feel like a huge dork now; I spent a couple of hours thinking about it. Thanks!)